# The canvas problem. ( ctx.clearRect does not working)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to create a break out game through javascript. I am wondering why the ctx.clearRect does not working. I want to put the rectangle in the y coordinate 430 to make it show at the bottom of the canvas. It moves when I have used the window.setInterval. But the rectangle move continuously.
Any help would be appreciated. Sorry for my poor English.

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 var position = 0;
 var yposition = 430;
 var length = 80;
 var width = 20;
 var xSpeed = length*1;
 var ySpeed = 0;

function R(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(position, yposition, length, width);
};

function C(){
  position += xSpeed; 
  yposition += ySpeed;
};

 window.setInterval(() => {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 430, length, width);
   R();
   C();
},150);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 50, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit are the parameters you're feeding into the clearRect function:

```
(0, 430, length, width)
```

Since **length** and **width** are hardcoded values of **80** and **20** respectively, the above means every time the intervals callback function gets fired it clears a rectangular area of 80 x 20 pixels at x = 0 and y = 430.

As your green paddle is moving you're actually clearing an area your paddle isn't located at anymore.

So you basically have two options:

1. Clear the whole canvas every frame
2. Clear the screen area your paddle has been before changing it's position

The second would look a little something like this:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var position = 0;
var yposition = 150;
var length = 80;
var width = 20;
var xSpeed = length * 1;
var ySpeed = 0;

function R() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(position, yposition, length, width);
}

function C() {
  position += xSpeed;
  yposition += ySpeed;
}

window.setInterval(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(position, yposition, length, width);
  C();
  R();
}, 500);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

I'd definitely recommend clearing the whole canvas though since there will be other on-screen objects beside the paddle.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. May I know why the program work after I changed the running step of function C() and R() ?